# How to substr array in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have array, I want to make selection in it, but before do selection
I want to take 2 numbers in front of each values in array:

```
$myarray[2] = array(62343,62444,62343,08453,62333);
```

I want something like this:

```
$arraysubstr = substr($myarray[2],0,2)
if(($arraysubstr) < 62) //not work (work for first array value) 
{
    redirect
}else{
    no problem
}
```

I thank all those who want to comment

Comment: what is the error or issue?

Comment: @DanishAli  i mention it in //not work

Comment: What do you mean by in front of the array? Do you mean to select two element after `2` index?

Comment: @SaadSuri i'am sorry , i have edited it

Comment: If I understand you correct, you want the first 2 numbers from the array index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_walk() function. It takes two parameters one is array and another is a function. You can perform any operation you want using the function on your array.

```
function fcn(&$item) {
   $item = substr(..do what you want here ...);
}

array_walk($matches, "fcn");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_walk() function to walk through the array. It returns true on success and false on failure. Its accepts two parameters one is array and other is callback fnction.

```
$myarray[2] = array(62343,62444,62343,08453,62333);
function func($value,$key) {
    $item = substr($value,0,2);
    if(($item) < 62)
    {
        echo 'redirect';
    }else{
        echo 'no problem';
    }
}

array_walk($myarray[2], "func");
```

Comment: Please describe what did you change and why, to help others identify the problem and understand this answer